# Package conflict while publishing similar apps

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I need to publish two applications in android market which are similar in functionality and uses similar code base. The only places where these apps differ is client specific icons and some strings.

When trying to publish, it looks like my apps are getting package conflict. What should I do to avoid package conflict. I did some search on net and it looks like I have to change base package of my classes which just sounds weird. Is there any other option that I am missing.

Comment: hi ankit i don't see any other way other than changing the package name

Comment: Thanks Dinash... But that's so weird. maintaining code base is going to be horrible. And I don't even understand the reason for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is identified by the package name. Therefor the package name needs to be unique. Thats why everybody uses some domain names for that to create a unique package (domains are unique, too).

My packages looks like:

```
org.shufflecity.android;
org.shufflecity.server;
```

You can also add a subpackage for each client you have:

```
org.shufflecity.clientname.android
```

That should do the trick...

Comment: Hi Warren... What I am trying to avoid is lot of code change. So that maintaining code becomes easier for different clients. Otherwise maintaining different branches can be a real pain

Comment: There is no alternative. Changing package names isn't a big issue. I would recommend a stable non-client version and for publishing you just export it, change the package name and publish it.

Comment: Looks like there is no other alternative of this problem. I will go ahead and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you need to change as package attribute in your manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
```

Don't forget to fix all your staff in manifest file according to the new package name.

Comment: Don't I need to change package name of all classes if I follow this approach?

Comment: you can migrate from com.example.project to com.example, then you won't need to change nay package names.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Do you mean changing classes package names to start with with com.example and package name is com.example.project. I tried this approach but R file is getting generated in com.example.project package only.

Answer (score 0):

The package name HAS to be unique on the market. That said, you can still reuse the code you produce simply by making the common code an Android Library. Then each client subproject would have a different manifest specifying different package names.

Don't forget to create that package and to specify absolute package names for your activities in the manifest.