# Remove publish application from google play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-account

I published application and by mistake I uploaded old apk and unfortunately I have also lost my old key store. So console is not accepting new apk with new key store. Now if unpublish app,then can I publish app again with same name and package or not. What better I could do with this problem..? Or I need to change everything from application name to package. Please help.

Comment: You have to change your application `android:versionCode` and   `android:versionName` in your manifest file only after that you can upload it with the same package name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `packagename`. Same package name not accepted again. So rename your `packagename` with new `keystore`, publish your app again.

[More information here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788664/1405983)

Comment: Hey @Hardy thanks for the reply. But can I use the same application name or i need to change that also with the package name.

Comment: you can use same application name.

Comment: Okay So I need to unpublish application first, and rename my packagename not the application name and create new apk and publish. That would solve my problem am I right.

Comment: Yes correct. If you lost your keystore then you must do this.

Comment: Hey @hardy thnks for reply. But I have notice one problem that an  unpublished application will be  still accessible through url. Is there any way to make it unaccessible.

Comment: How ? Can you give me example for the same ?