# Google Play Store - upload APK with the same package as of an existing one

Tags: google-play, package, apk

Let's say there is an app on google play with its package (obviously). Can I upload another apk with the same package with different keystore? If not, can I do this if I unpublish the published one and then upload the new one?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756259/remove-publish-application-from-google-play-store) I need to change the package name and unpublish the published app and then I'll be able to upload the new one with different keystore. Is that correct? I wanted to add it as an answer but I'm not quite sure.

The reason for all of this is that the Organization name is mistaken. 
Can I just create a new key in the same keystore and keep the same package and then just update the app and the the organization name will be changed and the app will update on devices?

Answer (score 0):

Once the package is uploaded the key store will stay the same. You can reuse that key store for a different package. But once it is uploaded, you will always have to use that key.

Comment: So if I want to change the organization name the only way is to create a new keystore and change the application package? Can't I just create a new key in the same keystore and keep the package? I'm new at this.. would you tell me what options do I have?

Comment: From what I understand, the keystore - package name have to be unique. You could have the same keystore, with multiple package names.